# Kendo ui Icons don't show if I use template

Tags: jquery, icons, kendo-ui

I'm new in Kendo UI, and trying to build small application with kendo mobile.
I have list and want to put icon for every item but if this list is in template icons don't show

```
 <div data-role="view" data-title="" id="side-root">
   <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" data-source="splitViewCategories" data-template="categoriesTemplate">
   </ul>
 </div>
 <script id="categoriesTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <a data-icon="about" href="">Category</a>
 </script>
```

If I use ready list like this

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
 <li data-icon="about"><a>about</a></li>
 <li data-icon="action"><a>action</a></li>
 <li data-icon="add"><a>add</a></li>                    
</ul>
```

I can see icons

Comment: Did you realize that your `href` is not correctly (at least) typed? It says `href="` when it should have the closing `"` and maybe some link?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `data-icon` you should add a `span` element with the `class` of the icon that you want to add. For example:

```
<script id="categoriesTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a href="\\#"><span class="km-icon km-about"></span>Category</a>
</script>
```